# XSS leaking into other parts of site

Tags: security, web, xss

I've got a web application in which there are several XSS vulnerabilities on it, on the Profile Page for example there is a text box which is vulnerable to XSS along with the Messages Page. They both have text boxes yet when I add some XSS into the Profile Page, the pop up also comes up in the messages section and I can't figure out why. I've attached some screenshots for more information. If anyone can explain why this does this, I'd be very grateful.

The below Links are for visuals of the application

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

These are the source code images/files
Profile Page Source Code:

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fA_Zoa7z4fdhBBzW2-e3Wm-fWF1qwXw7/view?usp=sharing
```

Message Page Code:

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YApsri_3YSmUwlRfyajcebgpe26L37TZ/view?usp=sharing
```

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting the saved data from this text box onto the `messages.php` page. If you right-click and inspect the "testtest" text, you'll notice a script was also added in there (the one you added earlier). By saving this server-side it allows it to be run each time the client loads the page because the browser still reads it as code to be ran. It should not - it should view it as text.

You'll notice that the first word in the background "test" is written, and the script has appeared. This is a blocking script, meaning no further code will be ran until you click the OK button in the dialog allowing the code to continue rendering the rest of the content on the page; hence why the second "test" word waits until you click okay before rendering the rest of the page.

Please let me know if I've missed anything out. Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Horkrine: I'm still a bit confused as to how its getting saved from the Profile page text box into the Messages Page as both boxes are independent from one another surely? When I looked at the background code I couldn't see how it was getting saved to the other page. Unless the script it being saved as apart of the Profile heading itself, so when the other page is opened it checks all links and then the script gets called during this process? If i'm wrong please feel free to correct me. If you need any more info let me know